How can build React-Native in iOS, build Error
I keep getting script issues, iPhone version range issues, and simulator issues even when I try to run the simulation.
Any help is appreciated.
New to ReactNative. No one in my team can help me.
#Project Environment
mac M2
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
node -v
v20.10.0
pod --version
1.15.2

package.json
{
  "name": "labts",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "13.6.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.10.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.51.5",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "immer": "^10.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1305.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.2",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.32.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^4.5.1",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.85",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

PodFile
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '12.0'

use_frameworks!
#use_modular_headers!

prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'nexlabts' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'nexlabtsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end

##Xcode setting images
enter image description here

Error1.
When i install cocoapods.
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React-RuntimeHermes": In Podfile: React-RuntimeHermes (from ../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/runtime)

Specs satisfying the React-RuntimeHermes (from ../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/runtime) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Error2. When i run-ios --no-packager --simulator="iPhone 15"

Build description signature: fc1341421f84b87c5245d346c2c17b66 Build description path: /Users/nowonjae/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nexlabts-argvodqcybjfcybstpulfpghnzvm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/fc1341421f84b87c5245d346c2c17b66.xcbuilddata /Users/nowonjae/Desktop/project/NeXLabRN/ios/nexlabts.xcodeproj:1:1: error: Unable to open base configuration reference file '/Users/nowonjae/Desktop/project/NeXLabRN/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts.release.xcconfig'. (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts-resources-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts-resources-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-nexlabts/Pods-nexlabts-resources-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts') warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'nexlabts' from project 'nexlabts')

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations: { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B5AA2E84-4F83-4749-A986-A1FCE5E398A3, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 } { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B5AA2E84-4F83-4749-A986-A1FCE5E398A3, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 } ** BUILD FAILED ** ]

Err3. When i build in Xcode (Any iOS Simulator Device (arm64, x86_64))
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

#What I did to fix the bug
The processing method I tried was reinstalling cocoappods, deleting the Pods file, deleting the cache, etc.
1. reinstall node
delete node_module, package-rock.json.
then
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
yarn install

2. set Xcode read node
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node

3. Edit Podfile
platform: ios, "12.0" 
or
platform: ios, "14.0"

4. reinstall Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData 
or 
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

rm -rf Pods
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update


Xcode \> Product \> Clean Build Folder.


cd ./ios 
pod cache clean -all 
pod install --repo-update 
cd ../


npx react-native run-ios --no-packager --simulator="iPhone 15" 
or 
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 15" or yarn start > i(run ios)

I want to build.

If you're still facing the same issue, here's what worked for me: I had

platform :ios, '13.0'

in my Podfile, and I changed it to:

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported

After making this change, everything worked perfectly for me. I hope this helps!
